# Should I hide the version information from Contact Form 7 plugin and how to do that?

Tags: wordpress, security, contact-form-7

In a Contact Form 7 form, there is a div full of hidden fields which show, among other informations, the version of Contact Form:

```
<div style="display: none;">
  <input name="_wpcf7" value="1234" type="hidden">
  <input name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.9" type="hidden">
  <input name="_wpcf7_locale" value="pt_BR" type="hidden">
  <input name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f1234-p567-o1" type="hidden">
  <input name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="567" type="hidden">
</div>
```

In this example, 1234 is the post id of the contact form in the database, while 567 is the post id of the page where the form is in.

The Contact Form version is also in the links for the JS and CSS code of this plugin:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='https://mysite.com.br/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=4.9' type='text/css' media='all' />

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://mysite.com.br/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=4.9'></script>
```

The Contact Form version doesn't seems to be an information I would want to display for security reasons.

I searched in google for "hide contact form 7 version" and I did not find any relevant entry; I also searched here in SO for `wpcf7_version` inside the [contact-form-7 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contact-form-7), [without results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcontact-form-7%5D%20wpcf7_version).

So, should I care about hiding the version information? And, if yes, is there a way to hide these information without damaging the Contact Form 7 functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No,**

Unless you edit the plugin with some custom code which is not recommend. Why do you need to hide the version? There are many ways of getting version of plugins or WordPress, even if there isn't anything on the page that shows it. All source code is checked in to WordPress subversion Repo. I could easily see the different between lets says the CSS file and figure out the version your using.

Keep in mind the version that shows in the CSS file is placed there by WordPress to help with browser caching issues on changes of the file. If your worried about a hacker trying to hack your site I would just recommend keeping your site update to date and choose carefully which plugins you do install. Beyond that unless you’re doing a custom solution (not recommend) of a site which would be a lot of work to maintain.

Comment: I agree what you said are the best practices, and that a determined attacker will easily discover the version by comparing the code with the repo, but better safe than sorry, and make the information a bit harder to get could in theory reduce the chance of being hacked, if there is a way to remove these data without adding custom code which can be more dangerous than the info. Thinking well, it's better to add in the question if I should care to hide these info, so my question can be more useful to the community (people who saw that code can be in doubt about it, as I was)

Comment: I understand where your coming from, it would require mass amounts of customization to WordPress/plugins it wouldn't be worth trying to remove or care about them. If your worried about hackers trying to hack your site I would suggest using a plugin like [wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) that can help prevent automated scan's/attacks and different methods of hack attempts. There is no perfect solution but this would be a great start. IP blocking would be another idea, if you don't do business outside the country you live in why allow them to access the site?

Comment: I don't recommend IP blocking of course.... but it has helped me in the past when people attempt to proxy them self outside the country to attack some servers at my company. Be very carefully with IP blocking if you do decided to use it. – Tony 4 hours ago